# Clustering Point for StatePlane WKID 2236

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clustering

Does anyone have an example to point me in the right direction to utilize Clustering with the ESRI JS API working with a State Plane wkid: 2236? I want to provide a solution for an internal application just like the demo on ESRI JS website. Though, all our data and the application I'm supposed to update is defined wkid:2236. I've tried modding the demo code though either I'm overlooking something or it's not possible. If this isn't possible any suggestions?

---

I had overlooked the "spatialReference" option within the constructor. This gets me to the point of displaying the cluster symbols on the map. Though, when I click the symbol I received the following error and I included the call stack. Any ideas?

CHANGES TO ESRI POINT CLUSTERING EXAMPLE

```
<br />
var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": **432163.89125**, "ymin": **1451074.4432**, "xmax": **710435.747749999**, "ymax": **1626999.3528**, "spatialReference": { "wkid": **2236** } });<br />
...<br />
var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("**http://gisserver/ArcGIS/rest/services/BaseMap/MapServer/**");<br />
...<br />
var photos = esri.request({<br />
                    "url": "**js/testdata.json**",<br />
                    "handleAs": "json"<br />
                });<br />
...<br />
 clusterLayer = new extras.ClusterLayer({<br />
                "data": photoInfo.data,<br />
                "distance": 100,<br />
                "id": "clusters",<br />
                "labelColor": "#fff",<br />
                "labelOffset": 10,<br />
                **"spatialReference":"2236"**,<br />
                "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,<br />
                "singleColor": "#888",<br />
                "singleTemplate": popupTemplate<br />
            });<br />
<br />
```

**ERROR**
Unhandled exception at line 34, column 167548 in http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.1

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'toJson'

**CALL STACK**

> toJson [arcgis] Line 34 Script
>       updateHighlight [PopupBase.js] Line 19  Script
>       onSelectionChange [Popup.js] Line 19    Script
>       select [PopupBase.js] Line 19   Script
>       _updateFeatures [PopupBase.js] Line 19  Script
>       setFeatures [PopupBase.js] Line 19  Script
>       _2b5 [arcgis] Line 15   Script
>       setFeatures [Popup.js] Line 19  Script
>       _addSingles [eval code] Line 275    Script
>       onClick [eval code] Line 126    Script
>       advice [arcgis] Line 15 Script
>       _504 [arcgis] Line 15   Script
>       _onClickHandler [arcgis] Line 34    Script
>       Anonymous Function [arcgis] Line 15 Script

Comment: Do you have a link tag to the popup css?

Answer (score 2):

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html

Did you try putting it in the constructor? 
From Esri -
SpatialReference. Optional. Spatial reference for all graphics in the layer. This has to match the spatial reference of the map. Default is 102100. Omit this if the map uses basemaps in web mercator.

```
clusterLayer = new extras.ClusterLayer({ 
      "data": photoInfo.data,
      "distance": 100,
      "id": "clusters", 
      "labelColor": "#fff",
      "labelOffset": 10,
      "spatialReference":"YourValueHere",
      "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
      "singleColor": "#888",
      "singleTemplate": popupTemplate
    });
```